# Using Java 8 streams, how to transform Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> to Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So I have a  `Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>>` and I want to transform it to `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` where the first Integer key represents numbers 1,2,3.....(the index of the current entry taken from the first map) and the second Integer gives me the size of the `List<Person>`.
The String in the inner map remains the same....

First I just tried to replace the second Integer in the map with the size of the list but it does not work.....

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> map2 =...
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = map2.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getKey(), Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getValue().getKey(), p->p.getValue().values().size())));
```

Comment: Maps don't have a defined iteration order, so *the index of the current entry* is non-deterministic. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a map doesn't have an index. You're probably trying to give the entries of the map a number starting from 1 based on the *insertion order*. If you're using a `LinkedHashMap` there's a way to accomplish this.

However, a `HashMap` makes no guarantees as to the order of the map. Also, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time; So, giving these entries a number will not always yield the expected outcome.

That said, you might only want to number the entries in the map from `1` to `n` where `n` is the size of the map and are not concerned in the insertion order of entries as mentioned above i.e. the first inserted entry doesn't necessarily have to be numbered as 1 and the second inserted entry doesn't necessarily have to be numbered as 2 etc..

Now, to the solution:

You can have a `List<Map<String, Integer>>` as a temporary result set and when you need the numbering of the entries simply loop over the elements and get the numbering with  `i + 1` where `i` is the control variable.

example assuming we have this list:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> temporaryResult = myMap.values()
            .stream()
            .map(a -> a.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            c -> c.getValue().size()))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

we can then get a `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` with:

```
  Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> resultSet =
                IntStream.range(0, temporaryResult.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i + 1,
                        temporaryResult.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

Note -

1. If the numbering should be based on insertion order this code will only yield the expected outcome if the map you're using maintains insertion order.
2. If the numbering is not necessarily based on insertion order of the entries in the map then this solution will work regardless of the map implementation being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a list to keep the order of the entries from the initial map, no need to store an index as a key of the map.

This will go through all the values of your initial map, map the `Map` to the one awaited with the `size()` of the list and collect everything into a `List`

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> map = 
    map2.values()
        .stream()
        .map(m-> m.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you really need a `Map` for any reason, the following code should work too

```
int i = 1;
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> newMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry entry : map2.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = entry.value().entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size())
    newMap.put(i++, map);
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying the for each loop, but it is not working yet: for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> entry : map2.entrySet())

Comment: @YassinHajaj you can fix your second code snippet with `for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> entry : map2.entrySet()){
            Map<String, Integer> map = entry.getValue().entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size()));
            newMap.put(i++, map);
        }` although the first code snippet is still incorrect.

Comment: You can then fix the first code snippet by using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy` and make sure you have parentheses in the right places to make it compile.